# Cannot read property 'getContext' of null error with ChartJS and Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, chart.js

I am trying to create a chart in my Meteor app using ChartJS. However it looks like the canvas element is not being read by my JavaScript.

From research into other answers, the reason for this is because the JS is being read before the HMTL canvas element is created, resulting in the null value.

However I have placed the JS to create the chart in my onRendered section in my meteor app, which should resolve it.

If I put the JS inside a script tag after the canvas element in my HTML, the chart renders.

Is there a solution where I can keep the JS code in my JS file instead of having all of the code in a script tag?

Here is the code:

JS

```
var Chart = require('chart.js');

Template.Dashboard_page.onRendered(function dashboardOnRendered() {

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

    // Create gradient
    grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(170.000, 600.000, 150.000, 0.000);

    // Add colors
    grd.addColorStop(0.000, 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.200, 'rgba(191, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.400, 'rgba(221, 255, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.600, 'rgba(255, 229, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(0.800, 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1.000)');
    grd.addColorStop(1.000, 'rgba(255, 50, 0, 1.000)');




    var data = {
        labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"],
        datasets: [
            {
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: grd,
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 1,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                data: [0, 100, 250, 400, 400, 400, 500, 700, 900, 1000, 1000, 1300, 1300, 1100, 900, 700, 500, 300, 100, 0],
                spanGaps: false,
            }
        ]
    };


    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true,
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            return value + '°';
                        },
                        mirror: true,
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        drawBorder: false,

                    },
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
            },

        },
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Seeing the same thing Meteor 1.5.1